# Google Bigquery table decorators

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to add decorators that will represent from 6 days ago till now.

how should I do it?

lets say the date is realative 604800000 millis from now and it's absolute is 1427061600000

- @-604800000
- @1427061600000
- @now in millis - 1427061600000
- @1427061600000 - now in millis

Is there a difference by using relative or absolute times?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
@-518400000--1
```

Will give you data for the last 6 days (or last 144 hours).

Answer (score 1):

I think all you need is to read [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/table-decorators).

Basically, you have the choice of `@time`, which is time since Epoch (your `@1427061600000`). You can also express it as a negative number, which the system will interpret as `NOW - time` (your `@-604800000`). These both work, but they don't give the result you want. Instead of returning all that was added in that time range, it will return a snapshot of your table from 6 days ago....

Although you COULD use that snapshot, eliminate all duplicates between that snapshot and your current table, and then take THOSE results as what was added during your 6 days, you're better off with :

Using time ranges directly, which you cover with your 3rd and 4th lines. I don't know if the order makes a difference, but I've always used `@time1-time2` with `time1<time2` (in your case, `@1427061600000 - now in millis`).